# Error in function using doParallel and foreach

Tags: r

I am trying to reproduce a code I found to download trading data and it was supposed to be working fine, but when I run this function I get an error, and I can't find a solution. Here it is:

```
Get_Candlesticks <- function(
  pairs, interval, startTime, endTime, path_save = NULL){
  # Download all trading pairs for the specified period
  start_timer <- Sys.time()
  data <- foreach(i = pairs, .packages = c("httr", "foreach"),
                  .export = c("Binance_Candlesticks_Historical", "Binance_Candlesticks_Timed")) %dopar% { 
                    response <- Binance_Candlesticks_Historical(symbol = i, interval = interval,
                                                                startTime = startTime, endTime = endTime)
                    if(nrow(response) == 0){
                       stop(paste0("Trading pair ", i, " has no data for this period!")) 
                      }
                  cat(paste0("Trading pair ", i, " downloaded."))
                  return(response) 
                  }
  names(data) <- pairs
  end_timer <- Sys.time()
  time_taken <- end_timer - start_timer
  cat(paste0("Downloaded ", length(pairs), " trading pairs in"), time_taken, "\n")
  # If no path for saving is provided, download data to R object
  if(is.null(path_save)){
    cat(paste0("All ", length(pairs), " pairs downloaded as R object."), "\n")
    return(data) }
  # If path for saving is provided, save data to path
  else {
    foreach(i = pairs) %dopar% {
      # Download data
      temp_data <- data[[i]]
      # Save the candlesticks for current the trading pair
      write.csv(
        x = temp_data,
        file = file.path(path_save, paste0(i, ".csv")), row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE
      )
      cat(paste0("Trading pair ", i, " saved as .csv file.")) }
    cat(paste0("All ", length(pairs), " pairs saved to ", path_save), "\n")
    return(time_taken) 
   }
}
```

When I call the function:

```
    Get_Candlesticks(pairs="BTCUSDT",interval="1m",startTime="2021-01-01", endTime="2021-01-02",path_save=NULL)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "non-numeric argument to binary operator"
Called from: e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data)
```

For completeness, these are the two functions called by the above function:

```
library (dplyr) # Data Manipulation 
library (magrittr)  # Pipe - Operators 
library (tidyr) # Data Tidying
library (reshape2 ) # Data Reshaping 
library (tibble)    # Data Frame Format 
library (readr) # Read Data
library (foreach)   # Iterative Computing
library (doParallel)    # Parallel Backend for foreach 
library (compiler)  # Byte Code Compiler
library (purrr) # Functional Programming
library (anytime)
library (lubridate)

# Binance candlesticks Timed
Binance_Candlesticks_Timed <- function( symbol, interval, startTime){
  # Set URL to API endpoint
  api_url <- "https://api.binance.com" 
  req_url <- "api/v1/klines"
  # Define the parameters for the API call
  params <- list(symbol = symbol, interval = interval,
                 startTime = startTime)
  response <- content(GET(api_url, path = req_url, query = params))
  # Restructure the response
  response_df <- as.data.frame(
    foreach(i = 1:length(response), .combine = rbind) %do% {
      foreach(j = 1:12, .combine = c) %do% {
        response[[i]][j] }
    }
    , stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
  # Filter and name the response
  response_df <- response_df[,-12]
  cols_numeric <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 7 ,8,9,10,11)
  response_df[, cols_numeric] = apply(response_df[, cols_numeric], 2, function(x) as.numeric(x))
  colnames(response_df) <- c("Open_time", "Open",
                             # Make the call
                             "High",
                             "Low",
                             "Close",
                             "Volume",
                             "Close_time", "Quote_asset_volume", "Number_of_trades", "Taker_buy_base_asset_volume", "Taker_buy_quote_asset_volume")
  # Return the response
  return(response_df) 
  }

# Binance Candlesticks Historical
Binance_Candlesticks_Historical <- function(symbol, interval, startTime, endTime){
  # Check inputs
  if(endTime - startTime <= 0) stop("startTime must be before endTime!") 
  # Initial data setup
  data <- Binance_Candlesticks_Timed(symbol = symbol, interval = interval, startTime = startTime) 
  # Set start time for while loop
  next_startTime <- startTime + 60000000
  # Get all full api calls
  while(next_startTime <= endTime){
    next_data <- Binance_Candlesticks_Timed(symbol = symbol, interval = interval,
                                            startTime = next_startTime) 
    data <- rbind(data, next_data)
    next_startTime <- next_startTime + 60000000
  }
  # Cut data to start and end time
  data <- data[which(data$Open_time <= endTime),] 
  return(data)
}
```

Comment: This error means that you supplied a function with a non-numeric (e.g., a string) argument where it was expecting a numeric argument (e.g. 2). That said, can you please take a look at your code again? It is not working on my computer due to various parantheses issues. Also, please make sure that I can simply copy and paste a minimal reproducable example. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The source of your problem is this line.

```r
while(next_startTime <= endTime)
```

because in your function call you are giving two strings.

```r
Get_Candlesticks(pairs="BTCUSDT",
                 interval="1m",
                 startTime="2021-01-01", # this is a string
                 endTime="2021-01-02",   # this is a string
                 path_save=NULL)
```

If you change your function call to the following, this error goes away.

```r
Get_Candlesticks(pairs = "BTCUSDT",
                 startTime = as.Date("2021-01-01"),  # Convert to date object.
                 endTime = as.Date("2021-01-02"),    # Convert to date object here too.
                 interval = "1m")
```

Unfortunately, this results in another error.

```r
Warning message:
In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Which is actually true when we look at the output.

```
Trading pair BTCUSDT downloaded.Downloaded 1 trading pairs in 0.7909036 
All 1 pairs downloaded as R object. 
$BTCUSDT
  Open_time Open High Low Close Volume Close_time Quote_asset_volume Number_of_trades Taker_buy_base_asset_volume
1     -1100   NA   NA  NA    NA     NA         NA                 NA               NA                          NA
  Taker_buy_quote_asset_volume
1                           NA
```

The reason for this is that the `REST API` does expect start and end time to be timestamps, i.e. integers. Which can be easily done be changing the function call to the following.

```r
Get_Candlesticks(pairs = "BTCUSDT",
                 startTime = as.numeric(as.Date("2021-01-01")),
                 endTime = as.numeric(as.Date("2021-01-02")),
                 interval = "1m")
```